# Correct way to write a ternary operation in PHP

Tags: php, ternary-operator

From what I can tell, there are two ways to write ternary operations in PHP:

```
$var = ( isset( $i['var'] ) ? $i['var'] : "" );

$var = ( isset( $i['var'] ) ) ? $i['var'] : "";
```

Is one of these ways "correct", or does one perform better than the other, or are they both interchangeable?

Comment: There aren't "two ways", there are an *infinite* number of ways, if you're going to consider the addition of parenthesis to be a new way of writing an operator. You can add an arbitrary number of parenthesis, it doesn't change anything. They're the same thing. You missed the obvious one with *no* parenthesis, and the only one that is arguably "correct": `$var = isset($x) ? $y : $z`

Comment: That would be the same as if you are asking what is correct: `$i = 1;` or `$i = ((((((((((1))))))))));` In only one case you really want to prefer the first one, and that would be if you nest ternary's, which you don't want to do.

Comment: Both forms have too many brackets: brackets are usually used to group logical operators like AND and OR. Neither are in use here, so the only round brackets in use should be on `isset()`.

Comment: Well there we go, you learn something new every day. Thanks for the downvotes, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct. And in fact in your example, you don't even need the brackets at all. You can just do this:

```
$var = isset( $i['var'] ) ? $i['var'] : "";
```

The brackets won't have any impact on the performance of your code. They are there for two reasons:

1. To remove compiler ambiguities.
   This doesn't apply to the simple example you've given, as there's only one thing being checked in the operator. You may need brackets in some more complex cases though.
2. make it more readable.
   Again, this simple example is pretty readable with or without the brackets, so it's not going to make much odds. But they may help you understand what's happening when you have more complex code, even if there isn't any ambiguity as far as the compiler is concerned.